# Rails - Unable to access parameters in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a **Restaurant**, **Cart**, and a **User** model. I would like to be redirected to a *Cart* form when entering a restaurant. This form will ask me for a table number and, thereafter, create a cart for the current user. However, when submitting the form I get a problem with the passed parameters

```
Couldn't find Restaurant with 'id'=
```

I suppose they are not in the white list but I cannot find how to allow them... I will be thankful for any suggestions!

**The passed params:**

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"*****",
 "cart"=>{"restaurant_id"=>"1",
 "table_id"=>"4"},
 "commit"=>"Create Cart",
 "user_id"=>"1"}
```

**I am passing the restaurant_id with a hidden field and the table with an input**

```
<%= f.hidden_field :restaurant_id, value: params[:restaurant_id] %>
<%= f.input :table_id %>
```

**In the cart controller:**

```
    def create
        @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
        @table = @restaurant.tables.find(params[:table_id])
        @cart = current_user.carts.new(cart_params)
    ...
    end
....
    def cart_params
      params.require(:cart).permit(:restaurant_id, :table_id)
    end
```

Comment: @Krisityan check the hidden_field html code and try to figure out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Couldn't find Restaurant with 'id'=

When you look into the `params`, you have `restaurant_id` inside `cart`, so you need to access it like `params[:cart][:restaurant_id]`. Also you need to change `params[:table_id]` to `params[:cart][:table_id]` as well to avoid another error.

```
def create
  @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:cart][:restaurant_id])
  @table = @restaurant.tables.find(params[:cart][:table_id])
  @cart = current_user.carts.new(cart_params)
    ...
end
```

Comment: Yep, thats it!! Thank you :) Will accept the answer in 7 minutes

Comment: Don't forget to update your strong params declaration as well - `params.require(:cart).permit(cart: [:restaurant_id, :table_id])`

Comment: @jeffdill2 You are wrong! It should stay unchanged.

Comment: Ah, right. `cart` is already being `required`. Brain fart. Excellent use of an exclamation mark to really drive home the fact that I was mistaken. ;-)